# Jsoup intermittent 404 error - how to de-bug?

Tags: localhost, http-status-code-404, jsoup

Jsoup functionality is working great for me.

However, there is a problem. Running the same test a number of times intermittently starts giving me 404s. The line

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
```

always uses the same URL but occasionally starts giving the 404 error below. Once the error has occurred it keeps happening for that local URL - the only fix I can find is to re-boot my Windows 7 PC. Jsoup keeps handling other web based endpoints fine.

The URL endpoint is a local FitNesse wiki. Even when my Jsoup program is getting the 404s the actual FitNesse wiki continues to work fine from a browser. If I bring down FitNesse and bring it up again, Jsoup still gives the 404. These make me think it is not a FitNesse problem. Re-booting is clearing something that Jsoup is using?

Here is the error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://localhost/FitNesse.AaaTest
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at
```

Comment: Is it possible, that you run test often enough to get blocked by the webserver?

Comment: Where does the URL (http://localhost/FitNesse.AaaTest for instance) come from ?

Comment: ollo, the webservice is local and I cant think of a way my tomcat would block on usage every 10 min or so.

Comment: Alex, the URL is copy and paste from a browser URL into a Java JOptionPane.showInputDialog. Are you suggesting the URL might be dirty? Good thought! So I added a URIUtil.encodeQuery on the string to clean it, but it makes no difference. :-(